# How to remove single quotes that is automatically inserted in codeigniter?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

How to prevent in codeigniter to not insert single quotes around in our query?

When we write query in codeigniter it inserts automatically single quotes, like this:

```
 $this->db->select('id, ifnull(name,\'\') as name');
 $this->db->from('table');
```

which creates database error.

Comment: when we execute it it adds single quotes around wrong place i.e 'table'.ifnull('name,'') as name' here single quotes are need around function as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 $this->db->select('id, ifnull("name",\'\') as name', false);
 $this->db->from('table');
```

Is what you're after. The quotes are escaping to stop sql injection, be sure not to mix unsanitized input from the user.

I guess I should also note that using this false parameter will stop double quote encapsulation, if you're using postgres you'll probably need to encapsulate any kew words used as column names yourself. (see difference between `name` and `"name"`)

[Active Record - Selecting Data](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select)

Comment: I somehow suspect the OP is trying to build SQL statements by passing in bits of SQL code and expecting them to change the statement.

Comment: Yes I presume so, sadly it is the only way to pull off some queries.

Comment: In MySql "name" return same as "name" value

Comment: Ah sorry, probably want backtics in there or none at all. (too much postgres on my part!)

Comment: I had to use this when using CONTACT_WS it was finishing the contact like 'c'.'column_name)' instead of 'c'.'column_name')